# Find the longest circle way in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to found the longest way in networkx from node A to node A using only 10 other nodes in fully connected graph as shown below. Is it possible?

```
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(len(hashlist)):
    for j in range(len(hashlist)):
        if i!=j:
           connection=(i,j)
           size=hashlist[i]-hashlist[j]
           G.add_edge(i, j, weight=size)
```

Comment: Where's the graph?

Comment: And what's hashlist?

Answer (score 1):

This will find the longest cycle in a directed graph.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]).to_directed()

a = sorted(list(nx.simple_cycles(G)), key = lambda s: len(s)) 
print(a[-1])
```

The same approach will work for weighted graph.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()   # or DiGraph, MultiGraph, MultiDiGraph, etc
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(0, 1, 3.0), (1, 2, 7.5), (2,3, 5), (1,3, 2.4)])

G = G.to_directed()

a = sorted(list(nx.simple_cycles(G)), key = lambda s: len(s)) 
print(a[-1])
```

Comment: I don't think this is answering the OP's question.  Since it's a fully-connected graph, I think the OP must be interested in a weighted graph.